# retrieve data from table1 but do comparision in table2 - Laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-query-builder

I have a query like below:

```
Relation1::with('relation2') 
->select('relation_1_columns')       
->where('relation_2_column', $relation2->id)  //Throws unknown column error
->where('relation_2_column', 1)               //Throws unknown column error
->get()->toArray();
```

If I do these:

```
Relation1::with('relation2') 
->select('relation_1_columns')       
->where('relation2.relation_2_column1', $relation2->id)  //Throws unknown column `relation2.relation_2_column` error
->where('relation2.relation_2_column2', 1)               //Throws unknown column `relation2.relation_2_column` error
->get()->toArray();
```

How do I do a check using a `where clause` to the table attached using `with`

Comment: do you have any relation defined in your relation1 model?

Comment: @Sohel0415 Yes, hasMany. Relation1 has Many Relation2. I want all the data of Relation1 where Relation1.id === Relation2.other_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
Relation1::with('relation2')
      ->select('relation_1_columns')
      ->whereHas('relation2', function($q) use ($relation2){
            $q->where('relation_2_column1', $relation2->id)->where('relation_2_column2', 1);
       })             
      ->toArray();
```